# Foundation, Designer and SQL Database in a Virtual Enviornment

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sql, virtual-machine

Are there any good tutorials that show you how to set up a web server, SharePoint 2010 Foundation & Designer as well as a database in a virtual environment (i.e VirualBox). I would like to learn how to install and use SharePoint Foundation & Designer and I've been told the best way is to do so in a virtual environment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are step-by-step instructions to do just that. Let me know if you have questions.

http://techriosity.com/installing-sharepoint-2010-in-a-local-virtual-machine-part-1/